# How to set page size of a grid

Tags: asp.net, grid

I have a grid it has to display some 100 rows from a table. I do not want to set any paging or sorting. How to display the grid with out any page size?

If I do not specify any page size then by default it takes ten and after ten if I add any row it throws an error.

```
<asp:GridView
ID="gvEventMechanic"
runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
AllowPaging="False"
GridLines="None"
BorderWidth="1"
BorderColor="Brown"
AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="Cyan"
HeaderStyle-BackColor="ActiveCaption"
FooterStyle-BackColor="DimGray"
EnableViewState="true" >
```

UPDATE

Removed allow paging.

This is the exact error.

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error:
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
The GridView 'gvEventMechanic' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't
handled
```

I have a add button down the grid which will add an empty row to the grid. If no page size is given it automaticaly uses 10 as default and while entering 11 items it gives me an option for `> >>`. If I click on `>>` I get the above error.

This is the code for my `add` button:

```
DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
drCurrentRow = _dsMechanic.Tables[0].NewRow();
drCurrentRow["Id"] = 0;
drCurrentRow["Description"] = string.Empty;
//Adds new row to the existing row
drCurrentRow["Passive"] = 0;
//Bind the new row with grid 
_dsMechanic.Tables[0].Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
gvEventMechanic.DataSource = _dsMechanic.Tables[0];
gvEventMechanic.DataBind();
```

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried just setting a page size that's larger than you could ever need (1000 or something)?

Comment: if i do that i can get that but is there any other way just too avoid hard coding

Comment: Setting `AllowPaging="False"` is usually sufficient. What's the error?

Comment: Error was "unhandled exception for next page event.."

Answer (score 0):

Try the AllowPaging="False" but if its not working, please check if there is a skin for Grid View that set the AllowPaging="True".

Answer (score 0):

Get AllowPaging="False" away from your GridView declaration because it is false by default. After that try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

If it does not help, please publish the whole error message and a stack trase. And also more GridView related code if possible. Perhaps you get your error not because of paging at all.

Comment: Removed allow paging. This is the exact error.                    Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The GridView 'gvEventMechanic' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled

Comment: actually i have a add button down the grid which will add an empty row to the grid.  If no page size given it automaticaly taking 10 as default and while entering 11 item it gives me an option for > >> If i click on >> i get the above error

Comment: so i need to make the grid to allow maximum number of Clicks in add button. I mean i can keep on addingany number of rows with out pagings

Comment: Could you please show what your add button does? Basically it is not clear what you mean by adding an empty row. Could you publish your code for AddButton_Click event handler? (please update your question, the code in comments is hardly readable)

Comment: This is wat it does...                DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
    drCurrentRow = _dsMechanic.Tables[0].NewRow();
        drCurrentRow["Id"] = 0;
                drCurrentRow["Description"] = string.Empty;
                drCurrentRow["Passive"] = 0;

                //Adds new row to the existing row
                _dsMechanic.Tables[0].Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                 //Bind the new row with grid
            gvEventMechanic.DataSource = _dsMechanic.Tables[0];
            gvEventMechanic.DataBind();

Comment: I've tried your code and it works withoug paging. I found no reason for paging to occure unless you unintentionally set `gvEventMechanic.AllowPaging=true;` somewhere else in your code, e.g. in `Page_Load`. May be it is worth to create yet another GridView with default settings and try to bind it with the same DataTable in your `add button event handler` just to compare the results of binding.